# If i compile any java program, i got this error

Tags: java

If i compile any java program, I got this error

```
b1.java:3: cannot access String
bad class file: .\String.java
file does not contain class String
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
public static void main(String ar[])throws IOException{
```

Comment: Are you compile a file called String.java

Comment: The title says 'any java program', but your post only uses 'String.java'

Answer (score 3):

As visible from your compilation step in the terminal,

```
String is already a Java-library class available in JDK.
```

Hence,you can't give such name to your program/class.

Hence,you receive such error.

Try naming it something else like `public class MyString` and rename your source code as `MyString.java`---recompile it and then you won't receive such errors.

Answer (score 0):

String is a datatype defined within the Java-Library. You cannot name a variable as String or any other name of datatypes, in that way you cannot name it for a class.

Answer (score 0):

String is in-built Class in Java. Hence you can not give the name for Class as String. you can check it by - just give the name for Class as  `Class string` and save it as `string.java` . now it will compile and run properly. but according to naming convention first letter of Class Name must be in UpperCase , so you can name it as `MyString.java`